# Disable the slide and delete on UITable view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Is there anyway of disabling the slide to delete function on a 'UITable' view? I have a table that displays the contents of a database but I do not want the user to be able to delete the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement this method in your `ViewController` ( or your other `TableView's` dataSource)

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return NO;
}
```